# Call to a member function query() on a non-object on line

Tags: php, mysqli

I can't seem to figure out what is going on here... or why this isn't working.  The code works on a different database... so I'm not sure what is going on?

```
 <?php
    //connect to the database
    $con = new mysqli("localhost", "rreedy", "quixtar1");
    $con->select_db("attendance");
    //display success or failure
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $con->connect_errno;
    }

    echo "<label for='evtCode'>Event</label><br/>";
    echo "<select id='evtCode' class='form-control' name='evtCode'>";
    echo "<option value=1>Text</option>";
    $query = "SELECT * from tbldata";
    $result = $con->query($query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            echo $row['courseName'];
    echo "</select>";


?>
```

Comment: What is `$mysqli` ??

Comment: Ultimately, what I want is for the query output to be the <option> tags inside the select.

Comment: You are totally wrong and php tells you about it - your object $mysqli is not defined and php can not call its method `query`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mysqli` object is in `$conn`. You're also mixing procedural and object oriented together.

```
echo "<option value=1>Text</option>";
$query = "SELECT * from tbldata";
$result = $con->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        echo $row['courseName'];
echo "</select>";
```

#### What I changed

- `$con->query()`
- `$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)`

#### The docs

- [query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)
- [fetch_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Comment: Thank you,   I can't believe I missed that mistake,  much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo, it should be:

```
$result = $con->query($query);
```